# catch of http request not getting called with jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I'm struggling to have a `catch` method called in my test of a `http` request, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I already compared my test with lthers found here, but I cannot what I'm missing.

That is the method I want test:

```
public get(apiName, methodName) {
  return this.http.get(this.url + apiName + "/" + methodName, {
    headers: headers,
    search: params
  }).catch((error) => {
    this.backendErrorService.notify(this.handleError(error));

    return Observable.throw(error);
  });
}
```

If I run the test, the method above gets called and I can even check if `this.http.get` has been called, but I can not make the `catch` to get called.

That is my test:

```
it("should show modal when contract service throws", fakeAsync(() => {
  // Arrange
  let http = TestBed.get(Http);
  let backendService = TestBed.get(BackendErrorService);
  let backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockError(new MockError(new ResponseOptions({ type: ResponseType.Error, status: 404, body: {} })));
  });

  let httpClientService: HttpClientService = new HttpClientService(http, backendService);

  httpClientService.get("ContractApi", "GetContracts");

  // Act
  fixture.detectChanges();

  tick();

  // Assert
  console.log(fixture.debugElement);
}));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure without understanding more about what you are trying to achieve, but I find it much more simple to provide a jasmine spy object or `spyOn(service.http, 'get')` instead of the real http service.  This would allow you to do something like `mockHttp.get.and.returnValue(Observable.throw(error))`.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer to your issue, please post it as an answer instead of as an edit [see this for why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a subscription.

As it's an **Observable**, if there are no subscribers, the call is not going to be made, here the complete solution:

```
it("should show modal when contract service throws", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Arrange
    let http = TestBed.get(Http);
    let backendService = TestBed.get(BackendErrorService);
    let backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockError(new MockError(new ResponseOptions({ type: ResponseType.Error, status: 404, body: {} })));
    });

    let httpClientService = new HttpClientService(http, backendService);

    httpClientService.get("ContractApi", "GetContracts").map((res: Response) => {}).subscribe((contracts) => {
    });

    // Act
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick();

    // Assert
    console.log(fixture.debugElement);
}));
```